# Invalid JWT on a graphQL query using next.js and nest.js

Tags: next.js, graphql, nestjs

I'd like to setup a simple auth guard on a nest.js API.

I'm using `next-auth` to handle authentication in my client.

Here are the essential bits: first of all, the auth options for next-auth. Using the logs, I can see that an access token is properly attached to my session.

```
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token = Object.assign({}, token, {
          access_token: account.access_token,
        });
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session) {
        session = Object.assign({}, session, {
          access_token: token.access_token,
        });
      }
      console.log({ session });
      return session;
    },
  },
```

Then, the query. I'm using [this library](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/announcement/frontend/using-apollo-client-with-next-js-13-releasing-an-official-library-to-support-the-app-router/) to create the query client, and then use it like this:

```
const client = getClient();
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
const authorization = `Bearer ${session.access_token}`;
console.log("authorization", authorization);
const { data } = await client.query({
  query: gql`
    query Rooms {
      rooms {
        name
      }
    }
  `,
  context: {
    headers: {
      authorization,
    },
  },
});
```

Again, the log shows that I have a properly formatted token

But the auth guard raises an error, saying that the token is malformed. Here is the guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard {
  constructor(private jwtService: JwtService) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);

    const request = ctx.getContext().req;
    const secret = process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET;

    if (request.headers.authorization) {
      try {
        const token = request.headers.authorization.replace('Bearer ', '');

        if (!token) {
          throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }

        console.log({ secret, token });
        const payload = await this.jwtService.verifyAsync(token, {
          secret,
        }); // this raises the error
        console.log('payload', payload);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

The logs show that the server has both the token and the secret.

Did I miss something? I made sure that the JWT secret is the same for client and server.